# Intellijj IDEA 2017.3.2 Lombok Api

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, lombok

Недавно обновил версию IDEA до 3.2, в окне едитора появилась странная аномалия вида недоступности помеченных полей аннотациями ломбока (`@Getter/@Setter` и т.п.)
[image: Some component]
[image: Class Player]

Покопавшись в интернетах, нашел решение только для компилятора:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.9</source>
                <target>1.9</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.20</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>../lombok-1.16.20.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Компилятор проглотил решение, и собственно говоря все вроде бы нормально - приложение собирается. Но сама среда подсвечивает мне зависимости. Также из блока настроек "Other Settings" пропали настройки самого плагина lombok (в наличии имеется)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная настройка включена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую JDK 9

Comment: Возможно не подключен annotation processing для lamboka. Вроде Intellij сама находит все процессоры, но возможно вы что то отключили и возникла проблема (или не подключили).

Comment: @Denis Vabishchevich, в том то и дело, что данная настройка включена. Так же ребилдил по нечколько раз проект, перезапускал среду - не помогло